# Error adding android as platform in cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am new to CORDOVA, I was building my first app. But when I invoke the command below to add to platform, I get an error.

The command I use is:

```
C:\myfirstphonegapproject>cordova platform add android.
```

I get this error:

> Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK
>   installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your pa
>   th. Output: 'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Its showing that your android sdk is missing. You have to install android-sdk.

Comment: Pretty obvious: you don't has installed [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) or if already installed your PATH environment should point to tools folder in the SDK.

Comment: Lol.. that much i also got..

it's installed properly here in my system.

Comment: @PeterMmm:: is the PATH  environment variable value should be that of TOOLS ??

Comment: I checked that way also..

it;s not working .. same error

Comment: something like this: set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\android\sdk\ **tools**

Comment: directly i am adding tools path to environment variable


D:\32 bit ADT bundle\sdk\tools


i have stored my ADT bundle in D drive, i don't think that's a problem 

@PeterMmm

Comment: No D: is no problem, but maybe your path does not get set correctly with spaces in path name ... On Win best to add to system environment. So when you open cmd.exe can you execute `> android` ?

Comment: Nopes :( :( :( @PeterMmm

Comment: Nopes ?? You cannot run android from cmd.exe ? SO is very pleased to people that correct spelling. Understanding Q's is easier when correct spelled and (we) non english-natives learn a little bit more about english grammar too.

Comment: okk it was just my opinion... It better be like that then...

and as far as my question is concerned no, i am not able to run android command on cmd, bad command or file name error ..

Comment: So your PATH is not correct. Set the PATH in system environment: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: i have to set User variable as we set for JAVA (TOP side) or we have to set system variable(Bottom side) ???

Comment: I have edited the title to be more meaningful hope you do not mind